# Can I change the language of ASP.NET Configuration Tool?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

My Visual Studio is in english but ASP.NET Configuration Tool runs in the os language because I don't work in an english country. How to configure it into english language if possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked the folder on my own machine:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\App_GlobalResources` and `App_LocalResources`.

The resx files are only in English on my machine, so I assume the language follows the language you installed the framework with. I installed the English version of the framework, thus getting English resource files.

If you get hold of the resource files for the English version of the framework, then you can either replace your existing files, or add them as `name.en-US.resx` and modify web.config to set the uiculture.

```
<globalization uiCulture="auto:en-US" />
```

This is the default on my machine, automatic depending on the browser language, and fallback to en-US (which is the only one present).